# When does the Instrumental Variable (IV) method fail?

Tags: correlation, arima, least-squares, instrumental-variables

Consider the following ARMAX model:
$$
y[k]=\alpha y[k-1]+\beta u[k-1]+e[k]-0.7e[k-1]
$$
where $e[k]$ is a white noise. One can see that $e[k]-0.7e[k-1]$ is a filtered noise and thus using ordinary least squares will not work as this will cause the regressor and the noise to be correlated. Let $w[n]\triangleq e[k]-0.7e[k-1]$

The IV method resolves this issue by introducing an auxiliary variable $Z$ such that:
$$
Z^{T}y[k]=\alpha Z^{T}y[k-1]+\beta Z^{T}u[k-1]+Z^{T}w[k]
$$
where by assumption $\mathbb{E}[Z^{T}w]=0$ and $Z$ and the regressor matrix are highly correlated.

Now $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are initally estimated by ordinary least squares and we obtain some bad estimates.

What is done next is defining the same model but free from noise:
$$
x[k]=\alpha x[k-1]+\beta u[k-1]
$$
given that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ were computed and we have $N$ date points, we can extract the vector $x$.

Next define $Z_{N}=[x_{N-1}\;u_{N-1}]\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times2}$. Note that $x$ and $y$ are similar in the way that they are both derived in the same dynamic way from the input $u$ (this is why $Z$ and the regressor are highly correlated).

Finally we solve $\theta=[\alpha\;\beta]=(Z^{T}\Phi)^{-1}Z^{T}y$

where $\Phi$ is the regressor matrix $\Phi\triangleq[y_{N-1}\;u_{N-1}]\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times2}$

**Question:** This method seems almost perfect except that there has to be cases where this method fails. Can someone provide me with an example and why it fails in that very example?

Comment: It will fail if $Z$ and $w$ are of zero correlation but causally related anyway. $Z$ has to be causally independent of $w$. I would recommend looking into the Directed Acyclic Graph version of causality (Judea Pearl is the champion) to find out more about when IVs work and when they don't.